# Is it good to specify related tags in tag info?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

In order to understand what I mean please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/svn/info, here is the list of related tags at the end of tag info. I feel like this is not a good idea since this list of related tags is subjected to changes, they can be added for example.

It would be nice to have some automatic process to get these related tags but putting them into tag info seems bad idea. Am I right or it is OK to have such a list in tag info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like at least 4 people thought so: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6708204

Imho, it's a complete waste:

Just listing related tags without rhyme or reason does not help anyone, we have the dynamic "related tags"-list when looking at questions in the tag which is perfectly fine for that.